Dom PDF laravel rendering too slow
I'm facing an issue with DOMPDF in Laravel PHP. The problem arises when I need to render a two-page PDF, which takes an excessive amount of time, sometimes up to 4-5 seconds. Despite implementing optimizations like converting images to Base64 and reducing CSS, the rendering process remains inefficient. I'm seeking further advice on how to address this problem effectively

Use other library, like WkHtmlToPDF

Can you please include HTML that you try to render?
